# Cannot make progression bar working on multi threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

The issue I have is related to the cross threading invoke for the use of progress bar between different threads.
I have a main function which generates a Form with a progress bar
this function calls another function with a Select which contains a call to a recoursive function and Task.WaitAll to have all asyncronous.
What I want to achieve is a progress bar step progression everytime that the "root" recoursion ends.

What I've already tried is pass the ProgressBar as parameter in both calls then Invoke the PerformStep.
Problem is that it looks like the execution is paused and if I actually pause VS from the execution I notice that the flow is stuck on that line.

```cs
private someArray; //this is not relevant

private void mainFunction(){
    Form f=new Form();
    ProgressBar p=new ProgressBar();
    loopFunction(p);
}

private void loopFunction(ProgressBar p){
    var tasks=someArray.Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => insideFunction(p)));
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.Cast<Task>().ToArray());
}

private void insideFunction(ProgressBar p){
   doSomething();
   p.Invoke(new Action()=>p.PerformStep());
}
```

Like I said what I get is the flow to stop at that last line although I've read around a lot and this seems to be the right way of doing it.

Anyone that can find the error?

Thank you very much

Comment: *Anyone that can find the error?* (whatever it means) ... the "error" is calling  `Task.WaitAll` on main thread ... **think that main thread picking something from the queue and run ...** `loopFunction` is posted on it and run ... then all your `new Action()=>p.PerformStep()`  are posted there too ... they will obviously not run until the `loopFunction` end

Comment: The point is that if they were posted in there the flow should keep going and the perform steps should all happen when it's their turn on the queue but it completely stops the flow

Comment: *The point is that if they were posted in there the flow should keep going* The point is that this is not how main thread works ... obviously thread can do only one stuff ... and it's waiting for `loopFunction` end ... then it will pick all your `p.PerformStep()` from the queue and execute ...

Comment: If you get rid of the `.WaitAll()` it should work fine.  Is there a reason you're doing that?

Comment: I want the main thread to pause until all the secondary threads are complete. I want to track the progress of the secondary threads in this progress bar.